# IBM Bluemix Zero-downtime deployment capability for cloud applications

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, continuous-deployment

We have a NodeJS Cloud Foundry application with a DevOps Delivery Pipeline enabled.

[image]
Initially we set up the pipeline to use the Active Deploy extension to the Delivery Pipeline in Bluemix to deploy app updates without any downtime. Also called: Rolling deployments, Blue-Green deployments, Red-Black deployments.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-rollingpipeline/cl-bluemix-rollingpipeline-pdf.pdf

Unfortunately, the Active Deploy service was retired swiftly as of June 23, 2017 as we are inhabiting downtime upon deployment.
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/05/retirement-ibm-active-deploy-beta-service/

How do we go back to the process by which a new version of an application is deployed into an environment with no disruption in service for the consumer? UrbanCode? Other options?

Answer (score 2):

A good way of doing this is to use the IBM Cloud Garage's [blue-green-deploy cf plugin](https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy). In your deploy script, add:

```
cf add-plugin-repo CF-Community https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org
cf install-plugin blue-green-deploy -f -r CF-Community
```

Then, instead of doing `cf push <app_name>`, do:

```
cf blue-green-deploy <app_name>
```

You can also specify a manifest, or specify a smoke test (if the smoke test fails, the build will be marked as failed and the original version will continue running).

Comment: Thanks @Holly Cummins. I just executed according to your suggestion. For some reason the new instance is not booting correctly "0 of 1 instances running, 1 crashed". However, with "cf push" it works perfectly and repeatedly. I am trying to look at the logs with "cf logs XXX-new --recent". Ant tip will be highly appreciated!  Excerpt from the logs: "Looking up 'blue-green-deploy' from repository 'CF-Community'
10935960 bytes downloaded...
Installing plugin blue-green-deploy.linux64...
OK"

Comment: Hm, that's strange. What version of the cf command line are you using? Does the application have a manifest?

Comment: Thanks @Holly Cummins. I do not use the CF CLI at the moment. Just the DevOps UI on BlueMix (see img above). No app manifest. I guess the next step is to install the CLI. I will be happy to hear any tips...

Comment: Ah, the build pipeline has a built-in CLI which runs the commands in the script you give. It will be a recent version. The next thing I'd investigate is the app name.

Comment: Investigate the app name for uniqueness / collisions?